# Variant data type in DB

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I'm looking for a way to have a variant column in my database (mysql probably), I know this is not possible, but what I need is a way to emulate this behavior.

I have a simple pair of tables like:

```
#task table
(
id int ..., 
date timestamp, 
owner int
) 

#info table
(
id int ..., 
relative int, #points to Task 
name varchar, 
value VARIANT
)
```

Basically I need to associate a variable number of information fields to each task, and each information.value would be of distinct type (string, datetime, bool and integer).

I've planned to create four columns of each type, instead of a single VARIANT, and populate the correct one. But that table will grow a lot (600Mb/month), and I think this will be a huge waste of space.

Does someone know a better way to accomplish that?

I don't know if this will let that even worse or better but I'll do this in django!

Comment: variable number of information fields to each task?  Sound like a straightforward many to many relationship.  If you don't know what that is, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: Well, no, it's a one-to-many relation. If you take a look at my question you will see that I have a variable number of 'Info' rows points to a single row in 'Task'. The deal here is to have multiple data types that fit in a single row Field.

Answer (score 1):

You are implementing something called an entity-attribute-value (EAV) model.  You've described it pretty well, in case you don't know what it is.

In terms of the data structure, string types occupy little space when they have `NULL` values.  But other types do occupy space, so you will have wasted space.  You could store everything as a string -- numbers as numbers, dates as YYYY-MM-DD, and make do with a single string.  You do lose some of the flexibility of a native data type though.

In general, EAV models are computationally expensive.  600 Mbytes per month is a respectable amount of data.  Pouring through gigabytes of data to bring records back together can be painful in MySQL (which has poor performance for `group by`).  I generally recommend a hybrid EAV model, where a "regular" record stores commonly used attributes and the EAV piece is only there for the uncommon attributes.