# What is the best way to Model this DB?

Tags: database-design

We have a scenario where we need to store Borrowing Permits of different users against their user ids. We have the following fields in our table.

```
Table:BorrowingPermits
Columns: userId, permittedAmount
```

Now, the requirement is that, even if an amount is not available for the user in this table, a default amount needs to be applicable for the user. And this default amount is editable from the screen so we need to store it in the database anyway.

I have thought of the following ways

1. Add a new column `type` which can take either of the values `default/user` to store the default value also in the same table. In this case,  I wont be able to use user id as primary key anymore.
2. Create a separate table which stores only one row, which is the default value. Here, one table needs to be created just for this value. And there wont be any relation between the tables also.

What is the best way to do this? I have checked the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758085/what-is-the-best-way-to-store-a-single-value-in-a-mysql-db) which is related to point 2.

Comment: There will be just one default value, so I wouldn't store it in the same table as another type of permitted amount. You can put it in a table of its own (not a problem, it's not like you can run out of tables this way) or if you're in a mood for some over-engineering, make a table `default_values (name, value)`.